# Hierarchy table - activation of rows through javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a database-driven hierarchy table with 3 hierarchy levels. It works almost exactly how I want it to, but the javascript code that drives its functionality is UGLY. I would like to re-write some of it, but I don't quite know how. I imagine I'll have to use recursive functions, but there are some strange business rules that may make it more difficult than I imagined. Can you make any suggestions to simplify my current code (in particular, the `ActivateRow()` function)?  See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/74zr3zgh/3/).

Note that there is some funky use of hidden fields due to ASP.NET Web Forms postbacks and losing input values, but there are some useful data-attributes written into the HTML such as `data-region-id`, `data-subregion-id`, `data-market-id`, and `data-hierarchy-id`. the main requirements are below:

- There are two tables - the first is linked to the second, so all actions on the first table should be carried out on the second table as well (though the second table is slightly different).
- Three levels of hierarchy. The highest level (Region), a middle level (Sub Region), and a final level (Market)
- Row activation enables all controls in a given row. If the activated row is a Sub Region row, it deactivates its parent Region row controls and its sales values sum up to the Region level. This does not apply to activating a Market row.
- Similarly, row deactivation should disable and clear all controls within that row. If the row is a parent row, it should clear all children rows and disable their controls as well.
- Deactivating all children of a parent row should deactivate the parent row and clear all parent row controls.

Surely, there's a better alternative. Am I reinventing the wheel? Is there anything out there that I could use to improve my spaghetti code? I realize this isn't the best question for Q&A format - is there somewhere else I should ask my question?

Comment: You should try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I assumed this wasn't the best place to ask but wasn't aware of that subdomain.

Comment: Note that Code Review *requires* the code to be embedded in the question. Also, I suggest you use Stack Snippets (Ctrl+M) instead of a fiddle, so that the code can run on-site instead of relying on a 3rd-party.

Comment: By the sounds of it there will be too much code to include, and most probably user doesn't or cant paste business code on the web. Some current implementation with abstraction would be useful but I can feel solving the problem would be easier by redoing the table thingy. Either way... I am happy to review my answer with any more details here or on code review.

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear what you are doing but from what I gather you have some kind of table you are filtering.

Also, you are using ASP.NET webforms.... so sorry for you.

I would not use any kind of form binding controls offered by ASP WebForms, because it is now obsolete, incorrect and very painful.

Instead, create an AJAX enabled page `[WebMethod]` that returns all the data or filtered with a parameter, what ever, in JSON (Because JSON is easier to read and debug, and much faster than XML)

Go and find the jQuery plugin [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/). Everykind of functionality is built in and extentable, it works great, super efficient client side, with varios filtering and searching capabilities.

You either create a new model on the Server side and remap the data server side, or dump your existing model and remap it on the client, either way, you just plug JSON data into [datatables](https://www.datatables.net/).

Saving back to webforms is slightly more tricky (compared to MVC/Razor) because you have to take the String and deserialise it to your model, its a few extra lines but I do this all the time and you can carry on with your business logic.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I created this monolithic user control in a web forms app and regret every second of it. Right now, I execute a stored procedure to get the model and use a .NET repeater to write out the rows from the database, including all the hidden fields and HTML5 data- attributes. Thanks for the reference, I'm familiar with DataTables but only used it for simple sorting and filtering. I'm currently looking into DataTable hierarchies (http://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html), but there are some additional requirements that may make it difficult to completely rewrite.